# Google Cloud Build + Google Secret Manager Substitution Problems

Tags: docker, google-cloud-build, google-secret-manager

we have a repository that needs to `go get` a private repo. To do this, we are using an SSH key to access the private repo/module.

We are storing this SSH key using [Google Secret Manager](https://cloud.google.com/secret-manager) and passing it to Docker using the `build-arg` flag. Now, when we do this locally, the Dockerfile builds and runs as intended. This is the command we use for a local build:

```
export SSH_PRIVATE_KEY="$(gcloud secrets versions access latest --secret=secret-data)" && \
docker build --build-arg SSH_PRIVATE_KEY -t my-image .
```

However, when we try to move this setup to Google Cloud Build, we run into 403 forbidden errors from Bitbucket, which leads me to believe that the SSH key is either not being read or formatted correctly.

The full 403 error is:

```
https://api.bitbucket.org/2.0/repositories/my-repo?fields=scm: 403 Forbidden
Step #0 - "Build":  server response: Access denied. You must have write or admin access.
```

What is even stranger is that when I run the Cloud Build local emulator, it works fine using this command: `cloud-build-local --config=builder/cloudbuild-prod.yaml --dryrun=false .`

I've tried **many** different formats and methods, so out of desperation I am asking the community for help. What could be the problem?

Here is our cloudbuild.yaml:

```
steps:
# Get secret
  - id: 'Get Secret'
    name: gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud
    entrypoint: 'bash'
    args:
      - '-c'
      - |
          gcloud secrets versions access latest --secret=secret-data > /workspace/SSH_PRIVATE_KEY.txt

# Build
  - id: 'Build'
    name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker'
    entrypoint: 'bash'
    args:
      - '-c'
      - |
          export SSH_PRIVATE_KEY=$(cat /workspace/SSH_PRIVATE_KEY.txt) &&
          docker build --build-arg SSH_PRIVATE_KEY -t my-image .
```

Comment: I’d recommend you set bash flags -e, -E, and -o pipefail. Did you give Cloud Build permissions to access the secret?

Comment: To look closer, can you provide the 403 errors for us?

Comment: @MrTech, I updated the question to include the errors. If you want a specific build ID, let me know how to get in touch.

Comment: @sethvargo, thanks - yes, cloud build has permissions and is grabbing the secret just fine.

Comment: Can you try dropping the &&? Also I *think* build-arg might ned to be SSH_PRIVATE_KEY=$SSH_PRIVATE_KEY

Comment: Thanks @sethvargo tried both of those suggestions but still have the same error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for all the help! This one was pretty weird. Turns out it's not an issue with Cloud Build or Secret Manager but the Dockerfile I was using.

Instead of setting `GOPRIVATE` with the command in the Dockerfile below, I was using a statement like `RUN export GOPRIVATE="bitbucket.org/odds"`.

In case anyone runs into something like this again, here's the full Dockerfile that works.

```
FROM golang:1.15.1

WORKDIR $GOPATH/src/bitbucket.org/gml/my-srv

ENTRYPOINT ["./my-srv"]

ARG CREDENTIALS

RUN git config \
    --system \
    url."https://${CREDENTIALS}@bitbucket.org/".insteadOf \
    "https://bitbucket.org/"

RUN go env -w GOPRIVATE="bitbucket.org/my-team"

COPY . .

RUN make build
```

Answer (score 0):

With Cloud Build, when you want to get local linux variable, and not the substitution variable, you have to espace the $ with another $. Look at this:

```
# Build
  - id: 'Build'
    name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker'
    entrypoint: 'bash'
    args:
      - '-c'
      - |
          export SSH_PRIVATE_KEY=$(cat /workspace/SSH_PRIVATE_KEY.txt) 
          docker build --build-arg $$SSH_PRIVATE_KEY -t my-image .
```

The `SSH_PRIVATE_KEY` is prefixed by $$ to say: don't look at the substitution variable, but look at the linux variable.

I also remove the && at the end of the export line. The pipe | means: Run each command in succession, line return limit each command